# Angular 16 package import issue

Tags: typescript, angular16

Hi I have an issue related to package 'angular-progress-http'. It works in angular 15 however its giving error in angular 16.
(import { ProgressHttpModule } from 'angular-progress-http'). I have explored various solutions but none seem to be right and doesn't work. In code I dont have any errors but when I run it errors out in the console. I have latest version installed in my applicaiton and using http client. Any help would be very helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Angular droped the compatibility with `ViewEngine` in v16.

[`angular-progress-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-http) hasn't been updated since 2017 (so it's not an Ivy compatible library) so it's not compatible with v16.

Comment: Hi @Matthieu Riegler, thank you for the answer. Is there any alternate package or way to solve the issue. I am stuck on this for days.